# How to fix anchor links that sometimes work, but other times jump to the wrong place?

Tags: html

Let me start by saying I am an absolute noob when it comes to coding. I hope this is the right place to post this as I am totally baffled.

I am using Wordpress Gutenberg to create a long article. I have a main table of contents near the top of the page (using the Table of Contents plugin). I also created anchor links within each section of the post to help ease navigation within each section.

Here is the link to help visualize: https://www.projectuntethered.com/best-gifts-for-travelers/

After finishing the post, I realized that the anchor links work at random. Sometimes they jump to the right spot, sometimes they don't.

For example, when I first load the page and click a link from the main table of contents, it doesn't go to the right place. But then if I scroll back to the top and try it a second time, it works.

The same happens with the anchor links within each section—usually the first try doesn't work and the second try does work.

Again, my apologies in advance if this isn't the place to post this. I'm new to this and didn't know where else to ask. Thanks!

Anchor link:

```
<a href="#hidden-pocket-shirt-men">Hidden Pocket T-Shirt</a>
```

Header it's supposed to jump to:

```
<h3 id="hidden-pocket-shirt-men"><a rel="noreferrer noopener nofollow" aria-label=" (opens in a new tab)" href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00E9DJA5U" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank">Clever T-shirt with Hidden Pocket</a></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
<a href="#hidden-pocket-shirt-men">Hidden Pocket T-Shirt</a>
```

This is what takes you to the top of the page.

Then change the link as

```
<a rel="noreferrer noopener nofollow" aria-label=" (opens in a new tab)"
        href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00E9DJA5U" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank">
        <h3 id="hidden-pocket-shirt-men">Clever T-shirt with Hidden Pocket</h3>
    </a>
```

Comment: Thank's so much for getting back to me! I feel ridiculous and a bit ashamed asking this...but can you explain this to me like I'm a toddler? I'm afraid I don't understand your recommendation

Comment: `<a href="#hidden-pocket-shirt-men">Hidden Pocket T-Shirt</a>` This link will take you to the `div` which has an id of `#hidden-pocket-shirt-men` Note how the URL in the address bar changes when you click on it.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! Turns out the problem I was having wasn't related to the code at all...DOH! As soon as I tried disabling the Lazy Loading plugin, everything start working perfectly. Sorry for wasting your time!